# English grammar question: Friend or Friends?

Tags: grammar

We are putting software update on our site and we hope our users can share this good news with their friends,

But which one is correct? 1 or 2?

1. Please invite your friend to download this new software.
2. Please invite your friends to download this new software.

I think without plural, it sounds like it is referring to a particular friend.

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Comment: It is not a grammar question, it is a semantics or psycholinguistics question.

Comment: The first implies a particular friend (or the only one you have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opening statement actually answers this for you i.e "We are putting software update on our site and we hope our users can share this good news with their **friends**,". Let me clarify this for you.

Both are correct and can be used. However, in your specific context and from a customer/user conversions point-of-view rather use "Friends", this would encourage the user to invite more than just one Friend.